# Auto-populate the image url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm checking if the browser is chrome or not. If that is chrome, then I am showing only Webp image with the attribute (data-mobileWebp) or (data-desktopWebp). Sometimes, webp images won't be uploaded in backend then I need to fall back to the normal image which is uploaded always like data-mobileImage or data-desktopImage

Here the code which is not working as expected is :

```
mobileImage = $('.mobileImages', picture).data('mobileWebp') != null ? $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('data-mobileWebp') : $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('data-mobileImage');
desktopImage = $('.desktop-images', picture).data('desktopWebp') != null ? $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('data-desktopWebp') : $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('data-desktopImage');
```

```js
var is_chrome = (typeof window.chrome === 'object' && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Edge') === -1);
var imageBrowsers = $('.image-browsers');

if (imageBrowsers.length > 0) {
  imageBrowsers.each(function(picture) {
    var mobileImage,
      desktopImage;

    if (is_chrome) {
      mobileImage = $('.mobileImages', picture).data('mobileWebp') != null ? $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('data-mobileWebp') : $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('data-mobileImage');
      desktopImage = $('.desktop-images', picture).data('desktopWebp') != null ? $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('data-desktopWebp') : $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('data-desktopImage');
    } else {
      mobileImage = $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('data-mobileImage');
      desktopImage = $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('data-desktopImage')
    }

    $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('srcset', mobileImage);
    $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('src', desktopImage);
  });
}
```

```html
<isif condition="${desktopImage || mobileImage}">
  <picture class="image-browsers">
    <isif condition="${mobileImage}">
      <source class="mobileImages" srcset="" media="(max-width: 768px)" data-mobileImage="${mobileImage ? mobileImage.getURL() : ''}" data-mobileWebp="${mobilewebpImage ? mobilewebpImage.getURL() : ''}">
    </isif>
    <isif condition="${desktopImage}">
      <img class="desktop-images" src="" alt="${'previewName' in contentAsset.custom && contentAsset.custom.previewName != null ? contentAsset.custom.previewName : '' }" title="${'previewName' in contentAsset.custom && contentAsset.custom.previewName != null ? contentAsset.custom.previewName : '' }"
        data-desktopImage="${desktopImage ? desktopImage.getURL() : ''}" data-desktopWebp="${desktopwebpImage ? desktopwebpImage.getURL() : ''}">
    </isif>
  </picture>
</isif>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Modernizr?

```
Modernizr.on('webp', function (result) {

  console.log(result);  
  if (result) {
    // Has WebP support
  }
  else {
    // No WebP support
  }
});
```

http://www.stucox.com/blog/using-webp-with-modernizr/